# NullPointerException while searching in DB

Tags: jpa

I have the following entity, `Customer`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "**Customer.findByEmail**", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email"),
(...)
```

And the following session facade method:

```
public List<Customer> GetPorEmail(String match){
    List customers = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByEmail").setParameter("email", match).getResultList();     
    return customers;
}
```

When I call the method, the result is always `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I am certain that there are emails matching the `match` in my DB.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your EntityManager is null. Please check whether you are injecting EntityManager reference properly and its not null.

Regards,

Comment: null?? i am noob in java ee please give me more info

Comment: Ok, just test 1 thing, code if(em == null){ System.out.println("null")}. If this code prints null in your console then your EntityManager is null. Do this test first.

Comment: Please accept this as answer and create a new question. I will answer there as this is a different question. Thanks.