# query to sqlite database going wrong

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

i have a query that writes to the sqlitedatabase on my android device

everytime I call the query i get an nullpointerexception,

here my query:

```
Cursor c =  onzedatabase.query(databasetabel, allekolommen, 
                                       waar, null, null, null, null, null);
```

after some research i found out that onzedatabase = null
although i use all the correct methods as needed (=>onzedatabase works for all the other queries on the same database)

in my opinion a solution is given in the following stackoverflow question:
[nullpointerexception fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006320/entitymanager-null-and-nullpointerexception-while-searching-in-db)

but how do i implement this solution on my android device, i don't uderstand anything of the answer

thanks for helping me in advance

edit:

here my initialazing of onzedatabase

```
private dbhulp onzehelper;
    private final Context onzecontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase onzedatabase;


    public static class dbhulp extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public dbhulp(Context context) {
            super(context, ADbAdapter.databasenaam, null, ADbAdapter.databaseversie);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }



    }
    public ABezurAdapter(Context c) {
        onzecontext = c;
    }

    public ABezurAdapter open() throws SQLException{
        onzehelper = new dbhulp(onzecontext);
        onzedatabase = onzehelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think, the referenced question is the same problem? Post some more code how you initialize `onzedatabase`.

Comment: i edited my question and added my onzedatabase initialazing, this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005863/nullpointerexception-while-searching-in-db) makes me think it should be the answer

Comment: Seems ok so far. Are you sure to call `open()` before you use `onzedatabase`?

Comment: ok, problem solved, stupid of me, thanks allot!! , how can i accept your answer since it is in comments?

Comment: I have put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `onzedatabase` is `null`, then most likely `open()` was not called before.